# Optimizar implementación algoritmo

Tags: javascript, jquery

El siguiente algoritmo comprueba si una cadena es valida siguiendo las siguientes reglas:

Dado un string de 10 caracteres numéricos:

- El décimo caracter numérico es el resultante de un cálculo y el dígito verificador
- Se trabaja con los 9 primeros caracteres numéricos de la cadena .
- Cada dígito de posición par (teniendo en cuenta que el primer caracter numérico esta en la posición 0) se lo multiplica por dos, si este resultado es mayor que nueve se resta nueve.
- Cada dígito de posición impar (teniendo en cuenta que el primer caracter numérico esta en la posición 0) se lo multiplica por uno.
- Se suman todos los resultados de las multiplicaciones realizadas anteriormente.
- El resultado de la suma anterior se resta de la decena inmediata superior.
- El resultado anterior debe ser el décimo dígito.
- Si la resta final resulta 10, el décimo dígito es cero.

**EJEMPLO**

```
0   7   0   4   1   6   3   5   7   5
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   
2   1   2   1   2   1   2   1   2      se multiplica caracteres pares * 2 y si es > 9 se resta nueve, e impares * 1 
_____________________________________
0   7   0   4   2   6   6   5   5   
|_______________________________|      se suma el resultado de las multiplicaciones, en este caso es = 35
               35                      Este resultado se resta de la decena inmediata superior, es decir 40 - 35 = 5, 
                                       y este resultado debe ser = al ultimo caracter de la cadena, en este caso 5. 
                                       Por lo que 5=5, comprobando que la cadena es válida.
```

Ejemplos de cadenas validas:

```
0106590284
1103487086
1003238829
1713695987
0201564820
1721926390
```

La implementación que tengo de este algoritmo, la hice hace algún tiempo atrás en la universidad, y quisiera ver si se puede optimizar el mismo, ya sea reduciendo código, o implementando otras funciones, el código es el siguiente:

```js
function validar(cadena) {
  var cad = $.trim(cadena);
  var par = 0;
  var impar = 0;
  var total = 0;
  var decena = 0;
  var resultado = 0;
  var longitud = cad.length;
  if(cad!=="" && cad.length === 10){
    for(i=0;i<longitud-1;i++){
      if(i%2 === 0){
        impar =0;
        par = cad.charAt(i) * 2;
        if(par > 9 ){
          par = par-9;
        }
      }else{
        par = 0;
        impar = cad.charAt(i) *1;
      }
      total=total+par+impar;
    }
    decena = (Math.floor(total/10)+1)*10;
    resultado = decena-total;
    if (resultado === 10) {
      if (ced.charAt(longitud-1) == 0) {
        alert("Cadena Válida");
      }else{
        alert("Cadena Inválida");
      }
    }else {
      if (cad.charAt(longitud-1) == resultado) {
        alert("Cadena Válida");
      }else{
        alert("Cadena Inválida");
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Longitud</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="ced">
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="validar($('#ced').val())">Validar</button>
<div id="salida"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes simplificar el código haciendo varias cosas:

- Reducir operaciones innecesarias (p.e. no hace falta multiplicar por 1 porque un número multiplicado por 1 será él mismo)
- Simplificar operaciones complejas (p.e. cuando calculas el resultado final, usas una función excesivamente compleja para calcular la decena superior `(Math.floor(total/10)+1)*10 - total`, cuando podrías hacer algo mucho más sencillo como `10 - total % 10`... aunque esto tiene algo más de chicha para el caso en el que el número sea un múltiplo de 10, pero se soluciona fácil).
- Reducir el número de variables innecesarias y las operaciones realizadas sobre las mismas (p.e. en el bucle llevas la cuenta de dos variables `par` e `impar` pero realmente sólo estás usando una cada vez y la otra es 0)
- Eliminar la redundancia de funciones y acceso a parámetros que ya has ejecutado/accedido con anterioridad (p.e. [el `length` que menciona eledgaar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22378/250) o el `charAt` de las comprobaciones).
- Arreglar errores y fallos en el código (p.e. guardas el valor del campo `ced` en `cad`, pero hay un fallo tipográfico y haces `ced.charAt(...)` que funcionará porque el navegador corregirá el fallo, pero no es ideal, además de que el código podría dejar de funcionar).
- En lugar de usar jQuery, usa JavaScript puro. Para lo poco que haces, estás cargando una biblioteca JS y usando funciones que son supersencillas en JS sin necesidad de nada más.

Realizando esos cambios en el código:

```js
function validar() {
  var cad = document.getElementById("ced").value.trim();
  var total = 0;
  var longitud = cad.length;
  var longcheck = longitud - 1;

  if (cad !== "" && longitud === 10){
    for(i = 0; i < longcheck; i++){
      if (i%2 === 0) {
        var aux = cad.charAt(i) * 2;
        if (aux > 9) aux -= 9;
        total += aux;
      } else {
        total += parseInt(cad.charAt(i)); // parseInt o concatenará en lugar de sumar
      }
    }

    // la parte más compleja: si es un múltiplo de 10 será 0, sino, 10-el módulo
    total = total % 10 ? 10 - total % 10 : 0;

    // la condición de arriba te la ahorras abajo, haciendo el código más claro
    if (cad.charAt(longitud-1) == total) {
      alert("Cadena Válida");
    }else{
      alert("Cadena Inválida");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ced">
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="validar()">Validar</button>
<div id="salida"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro, son muy útiles esas observaciones, ahora se ve mucho mejor el algoritmo.

Answer (score 1):

En la condición anterior utiliza `longitud` en lugar de volver a calcular `dad.length` dada vez, y en el bucle `for` no le restes 1 a la variable `longitud`, lo puedes hacer en el momento en el que la declaras; `var longitud = cad.length - 1` o declarar otra variable para este caso. El calculo del `length` en cada iteración del bucle es bastante costoso.